# What is Replacement of Trigger in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012

Recently I had attended an interview for SQL Server.

In SQL Server 2008 we have triggers to trigger the action while event occurs on table. What is replacement for triggers in SQL Server 2012?

Anyone knows please share....

Comment: I don't know what these interviewers wanted to hear - but triggers are still very much present in SQL Server 2012, and I know of no *replacement* for them .....

Comment: No actually... What new fuctionality is there like trigger in sql Server2012

Comment: There **is NO NEW** functionality like triggers in SQL Server 2012 - it still very much has triggers as ever before!

Comment: Ya.. i too searched dude.. I dono have to ask with interviewer again which will not possible again!! Lol..!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By luck, I spoke with one Dba. He told that t answer is CDC(Change Data Capture).. 
I am sorry this option is available @2008 itself....

This url refers

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166250/Microsoft-SQL-Server-Change-Data-Capture-CDC

Answer (score 1):

There is no replacement. Triggers are still a feature in SQL Server 2012 and SQL Server 2014:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: Yes dude. I accept that.. But which one is working like triggers? For that CDC is t correct answer